# Send data to a website using Microsoft Edge (switching from Internet Explorer)

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have this existing Windows form application written in C# that processes data and send the proccessed data to a website.

It is working fine in internet explorer but I want to it also to work on Microsoft Edge. is it possible to use Edge?

Here's my code.

```
   private void SendDataToSPC(SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie, string strSPCData)
        {           
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 doc = ie.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument3;
            mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection txtBoxes = doc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            string[] data = Regex.Split(strSPCData, "\r\n");
            int intCtr = 0;
            foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement txtBox in txtBoxes)
            {
                if (txtBox.getAttribute("className") != null)
                {
                    if (txtBox.getAttribute("className").Equals("vcs_de_textbox") && intCtr < data.Length)
                    {
                        txtBox.setAttribute("value", data[intCtr]);
                        intCtr++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement button in txtBoxes)
            {
                if (button.getAttribute("className") != null)
                {
                    if (button.getAttribute("className").Equals("vcs_de_saveButton")){
                        button.click();
                    }
                }
            }

            ((mshtml.HTMLDocument)doc).focus();
        }
```

**Update**

I currently using Selenium and I try to use Edge driver it returns me an error of

> Additional information: A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58191/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

But when I try to use firefoxDriver it is working but I need to use existing Firefox open browser session (existing open Firefox).

```
Selinium webdriver 3.141.0 
Microsoft Edge 41.16299.1480.0 - browser 
Selenium.webdriver.microsoftdrivere 17.17134.0
OS Windows 10
```

Here's my latest code

```
  private void SendDataToSPC2(string strSPCData)
        {
            //Create the reference for our browser
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver");
            //IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            //Navigate to google page
            //driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:www.google.com");

            //Find the Search text box UI Element
            //IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("p1d1"));

            //Perform Ops
            //element.SendKeys("executeautomation");

            //Close the browser
           // driver.Close();
            IWebDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver();
            edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://phgcubadm1ms023/spc/jsp/dataentry/vcsdataentry/vcsDataEntryMain.action");
            var txtBoxes = edgeDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("INPUT"));
            string[] data = Regex.Split(strSPCData, "\r\n");
            int intCtr = 0;
            foreach (IWebElement txtbox in txtBoxes)
            {
                if (txtbox.GetAttribute("className") != null)
                {
                    if (txtbox.GetAttribute("className").Equals("vcs_de_textbox") && intCtr < data.Length)
                    {
                        txtbox.SendKeys(data[intCtr]);
                        intCtr++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (IWebElement button in txtBoxes)
            {
                if (button.GetAttribute("className") != null)
                {
                    if (button.GetAttribute("className").Equals("vcs_de_saveButton"))
                    {
                        button.Click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and looks like you are trying to automate IE browser in your code.

You cannot run this same code for the Edge browser.

I suggest you try to use **Microsoft Web driver** to automate MS Edge browser using c# code.

Here is a code example:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System;

namespace EdgeDriverTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        /*
        * This assumes you have added MicrosoftWebDriver.exe to your System Path.
        * For help on adding an exe to your System Path, please see:
        * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537574(v=office.14).aspx
        */
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* You can find the latest version of Microsoft WebDriver here:
            * https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
            */
            var driver = new EdgeDriver();

            // Navigate to Bing
            driver.Url = "https://www.bing.com/";

            // Find the search box and query for webdriver
            var element = driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");

            element.SendKeys("webdriver");
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            Console.ReadLine();
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

References:

1. [Download web driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)
2. [Bringing automated testing to Microsoft Edge through WebDriver](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/)
3. [WebDriver (EdgeHTML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver)
4. [WebDriver (Chromium)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium)

Comment: hi just an update i try using selenium and firefox driver but its not going to take the requerement. because i need to use the existing open firefox session. Also why i use firefox because edge driver is not working on mine.

Comment: also if i navigate to the webpage i need to log in first and click morethan 5 buttons. so if only its possible to use existing open firefox

Comment: Your comment is not clear. You need to provide detailed information about what you tried to run the Edge web driver? which version did you try to run? Which OS build you are using? Did you get any error when you run a web driver?

Comment: From your updated information, it looks like it can be a configuration issue that caused this error. Your Edge version is 41.16299.1480.0 I suggest you try to make a test with web driver release version 16299. Ref: https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/4/1/D417998A-58EE-4EFE-A7CC-39EF9E020768/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe I also suggest you update your Edge browser with the latest version and use the latest web driver.

Comment: ow. in clients pc so if my edge automaticaly update my app will not work.

Comment: in that situation, you may need to update your app and configure as per new update to work properly with the Edge browser. did you test with the web driver release version 16299? Does it work? let us know about your testing results.

Comment: yes it worked, my concern is every browser update i need to update also the app

Comment: If you use the latest version of Edge (EdgeHtml) browser then you need to run the DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0 command to install the web driver. Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge Legacy versions 18 and 19 is a Windows Feature on Demand which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver. So I think it needs less frequent updates in your app. Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/